# Python: How to convert a list of dates into a list of days for meetings

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am working on a web app in Python/Django and I am trying to make a calendar. I am using Python's HTMLCalendar class found in the calendar module. I have the following in `models.py`:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
```

The `start_date` of the meeting is displayed in the following format: `2019-12-03 00:00:00`.

I am overriding the `formatday()` function in HTMLCalendar. This function takes a day as a one of its parameters. I have a list of meetings, and if the meeting is on the day that is passed to the function, I want the calendar to display those meetings on the cell for that day in the calendar.

For example, say that the day I am considering is the 3rd of a certain month. I want to somehow be able to extract the day of a meeting from the `start_date` value (e.g. extract the day 3 from the date 2019-12-03). However, I am not what is the best way to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# if you are getting your start date like this, then you have to convert start date into datetime object

from datetime import datetime

start_date = '2019-12-03 00:00:00'

# to show the day only in python

start_date_day = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').day
print(start_date_day)
```